# Reharper Short Cut to Autofix in C#

Tags: c#, resharper

I am new to resharper and I'm used to Java + Eclipse setup.  I'm looking for a short cut key combo that would act like eclipse does when there is an error on the line.  Press Ctrl+1 and a selection of autofixes will pop for the nearest error.

Thanks!

Comment: Alt + Enter? I'm not sure I follow you. What is exactly the result you expect?

Comment: So imagine I have an incorrect signature in a test.  Assert.Equal(1, Thing.Blah());  If Thing.Blah() returned a void then Ctrl+1 would open a context that would allow an option to change the return sig to an int on Thing.Blah().  This is true for Eclipse and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not really sure if this varies from setup to setup, but for me

Alt+Enter

works.